# codeigniter delete file from folder

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

please can anyone help me i want to delete file from folder codeigniter this is my controller

```
 public function delete($id = false) {
        if (!$id)
            show_404();
        $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
        $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
        if (!$data['item'])
            show_404();
        $this->{$this->model}->delete();
        redirect('admin/' . $this->module);
    }

    public function image($var, $id) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './cdn/sliders/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            if ($data['file_name'])
                $this->{$this->model}->image = $data['file_name'];
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please add more information. What errors is it showing?

Comment: there's no errors i just want that the delete function remove the row from database and also the file

can you tell me what you need to help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many thanks guy i got the answer

here how it works.

```
public function delete($id = null) {

        if (!$id)
            show_404();
        $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
        $path = './cdn/projects/';
        $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
            if (!$data['item'])
                show_404();
        @unlink($path.$data['item']->image);
        $this->{$this->model}->delete();
        redirect('admin/' . $this->module);
    }
```

Comment: you just copped my answer!!!, can you just tell me that what's the difference your and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

it's like

```
public function delete_video($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->select('video');
    $video_name = $this->db->get('vs_videos')->row_array();
    if ($video_name) {
        @unlink('./vs_asset/videos/' . $video_name['video']);

        $this->db->where('id', $id)
            ->delete('vs_videos');
        $result = $this->db->affected_rows();
        return $result;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = file_name_with_full_path
```

You can use unlink($filename) function for delete file in php

Please check below link for details

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp